# koa.js basic app always returns Not Found

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

I'm trying to write my first ever koa.js app, and for some reason I just can't set a route with a function. I keep getting a "Not Found" error.

Here's my code -

```
const koa    = require('koa'),
      router = require('koa-router')();

var app = new koa();

router.get('/', function *(next) {
    this.body = "Hello"
});

app
  .use(router.routes())
  .use(router.allowedMethods());

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Listening on port 3000");
```

This code is based on the koa-router github example

Then when I go to localhost:3000 I get "Not Found"
[image]

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried killing and restarting the app after you've made your changes?

Comment: Come on, of course. Having said that, I wouldn't be surprised if it's a really silly mistake, something like you suggested...

Answer (score 4):

Now function generator is deprecate in koa2. Used code like

```
const koa = require('koa'),
router = require('koa-router')();

var app = new koa();

router.get('/', function(ctx, next) {
 ctx.body = "Hello"
});

app.use(router.routes()).use(router.allowedMethods());

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Listening on port 3000");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting the same error but i found out that **maybe** this is the easiest way of doing it.

```
'strict'
const koa = require('koa')
const app =new koa()
var route = require('koa-router');
const host = 'localhost' || '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3123 || process.env.PORT;

// initiate the route
var my_route = route();
// defines the route
my_route.get('/',function(body, next){
    body.body = "I love routes"
});
app.use(my_route.routes())
app.listen(port, host,(err)=>{
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("The server has started")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but for anyone who is new in koa, and beside using the new way in koa 3, as i had same error because lot of documents and examples just confuse me, it is said that *routes should be last middleare to use* but not before settings routes so **you should write the line of using routes middlware before the code setter of routes** like that:

```
const koa    = require('koa'),
      router = require('koa-router')();

var app = new koa();

app.use(router.routes())
  .use(router.allowedMethods());

router.get('/', function *(next) {
    this.body = "Hello"
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Listening on port 3000");
```